# Invalid UTF-8 character string on import of a CSV file into a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, csv, utf-8

I'm trying to import CSV into my MySQL database using this code:

I get the CSV file from post.

```
<?php

//conexiones, conexiones everywhere
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = 'password';

$database = 'test';
$table = 'csvtable';
if (!@mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass))
    die("No se pudo establecer conexión a la base de datos");

if (!@mysql_select_db($database))
    die("base de datos no existe");
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        //Aquí es donde seleccionamos nuestro csv
         $fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];
         echo 'Cargando nombre del archivo: '.$fname.' <br>';
         $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);

         if(strtolower(end($chk_ext)) == "csv")
         {
             //si es correcto, entonces damos permisos de lectura para subir
             $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
             $handle = fopen($filename, "r");

             while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
             {
               //Insertamos los datos con los valores...
                $sql = "INSERT into csvtable(id, example, example2) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]'";
                mysql_query($sql) or die('Error: '.mysql_error());
             }
             //cerramos la lectura del archivo "abrir archivo" con un "cerrar archivo"
             fclose($handle);
             echo "Importación exitosa!";
         }
         else
         {
            //si aparece esto es posible que el archivo no tenga el formato adecuado, inclusive cuando es cvs, revisarlo para             
//ver si esta separado por " , "
             echo "Archivo invalido!";
         }
    }

?>
```

The problem is that I have words like `Sol·licitud` or `Accés` and I'm getting this error:

> Error: Invalid utf8 character string: 'Sol\xB7licitant'

Could you help me guys?

Comment: Make sure your whole stack is UTF-8: https://www.toptal.com/php/a-utf-8-primer-for-php-and-mysql

Comment: csv and utf-8 have problems. Import into Mysql using LOAD DATA. I had this problem when trying to export data from SQL Server to Mysql. Client gave me XML with problems. Don't forget to add `SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'` before `load data`. I also add `SET NAMES utf8` when working with MySQL and i18n .

Comment: If you're creating/editing the csv file in Excel - **don't** ... the utf-8 support is crap (you have to create a new spreadsheet then import the the data), try Open/Libre Office instead, you might have better luck.

Comment: Do not use `mysql_*` interface; convert to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: Have you tried Muhammed's `SET NAMES utf8` yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont know if this work for this case, but when I have text files showing wrong accents I just use `UltraEdit` or `Notepad++` to change the Enconde to `UTF-8`

[image]

Comment: @GonzaloPaniagua The word `Sol·licitud` is encoded in Windows-1252 if the bytes are `53 6F 6C B7 6C 69 63 69 74 75 64`. This word encoded in UTF-8 would have the byte stream `53 6F 6C C2 B7 6C 69 63 69 74 75 64`. Do you see the difference? There is `C2` before `B7`. Your CSV file is most likely not encoded in UTF-8 or just partly encoded in UTF-8. `Accés` is `41 63 63 E9 73` in Windows-1252 and `41 63 63 C3 A9 73` in UTF-8, i.e. `C3 A9` instead of `E9` for `é`.