# SQL Error 13000 HY000

Tags: sql, database

```
use defpass; 

create table creds (
entry_date DATE,
vendor VARCHAR(23),
username VARCHAR(13),
password VARCHAR(19),
comments VARCHAR(48)
);

load data local infile '/Users/baileystiles/Desktop/default-passwords.csv'
Into Table creds
fields terminated by ',';
```

SELECT STR_TO_DATE('11,3,13','%m,%d,%y');

Trying to load a csv file into my database and I get an error saying invalied uft8 character string 'backdoor'. The does have dates which need to be converted to strings well. Which I did with the STR_TO_DATE function

Comment: which db you are using  ?

Comment: @scaisEdge I am using Maria DB

Comment: Possible solution.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775687/invalid-utf-8-character-string-on-import-of-a-csv-file-into-a-mysql-database

Answer (score 1):

Try using NVARCHAR:

```
use defpass; 

create table creds (
entry_date DATE,
vendor NVARCHAR(23),
username NVARCHAR(13),
password NVARCHAR(19),
comments NVARCHAR(48)
);

load data local infile '/Users/baileystiles/Desktop/default-passwords.csv'
Into Table creds
fields terminated by ',';
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained why it solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Change the data type of the column to `nvarchar(..)`, then you will not be bothered by the `code page`

Comment: I tried that, and I am still getting the same error. -_-